# Cmd batch file configuration

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window, command-prompt, terminate

I am looking for a way to terminate a process and run another one afterwards. This should be done in the same batch file. And the only way to terminate the process is to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then say Y afterswards.

So the thing I want is the batch file to do is to automatically;
CMD: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
CMD: Y

call x.exe

So my question is how do I programatically do these step in batch script?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: you can terminate a task with `taskkill` which can be driven many ways, but possibly the easiest is using the process ID (PID) which can be easily obtained using `tasklist`

Comment: You can stop your script with EXIT /b.

Comment: @Sascha I dont want to Exit the batch, because there is some new batch call's thats going to happen afterwards. So I want to terminate the process only and create a new process afterwards.

Comment: @Magoo I tried the taskkill, didn't seem to work. I couldn't kill the task, but would it allow me to kill the task(process) and run a new one afterwards or?

Comment: Isn't there a way to let the script press CTRL + C and then Say Y to terminate the process?? Would be great if this was possible.

Comment: did you try the `/f` option

Comment: No, I didn't try this one. But what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, first, use the command `taskkill`. This will terminate the process you specify in the file's code. If that does not work, try putting one of the parameters given when entering `taskkill /?`.

```
/S    system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

/U    [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which the
                       command should execute.

/P    [password]       Specifies the password for the given user
                       context. Prompts for input if omitted.

/FI   filter           Applies a filter to select a set of tasks.
                       Allows "*" to be used. ex. imagename eq acme*

/PID  processid        Specifies the PID of the process to be terminated.
                       Use TaskList to get the PID.

/IM   imagename        Specifies the image name of the process
                       to be terminated. Wildcard '*' can be used
                       to specify all tasks or image names.

/T                     Terminates the specified process and any
                       child processes which were started by it.

/F                     Specifies to forcefully terminate the process(es).
```

Secondly, use the `call` command. Because I have never been in a situation where I had to use this command in my whole life, my definition may not be 100% correct. Sorry.

The call command is used to execute another batch-file. It has to be used in like this: `CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]`. Batch-parameters are used to specify important information required by the file. If you have file extensions enabled, the `call` command accepts labels as the target.

Here you go.